# Symplectic form for real solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

Consider a real Klein-Gordon field $\phi$ in a globally hyperbolic spacetime, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

The covariant Klein-Gordon equation is

$$(g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+m^{2})\phi=0$$

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real-valued solutions to this equation.

Define the following bilinear form:

$$(f,h):=\int_{\Sigma} d\Sigma_{\mu}\sqrt g g^{\mu\nu} (f\partial_{\nu}h-h\partial_{\nu}f), \forall f,h \in V$$

where $\Sigma$ is any spacelike hypersurface.

This is a bilinear, antisymmetric, non-degenerate form, i.e. a symplectic form.

How can I prove that it is non-degenerate?

Comment: Probably some kind of bump function. If f is nonzero somewhere, try picking some h which is 1 nearby and 0 elsewhere. Probably have to be a bit more careful since there are derivatives involved, try integrating the first bit by parts maybe?

Comment: I thought maybe you can find a set of basis $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$, and rewrite $f$ and $h$ by $f=a_1 f_1+...+a_n f_n$, $h=b_1 f_1+...+b_n f_n$ (it could be non-discrete), and then show that only when $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=0$ or $b_1=b_2=...=b_n=0$,  the inner product could be zero.

Comment: In this particular case, if $f=0$ whenever $(f,h) = 0$ for all of $h$, then the inner product you wrote down is nondegenerate. This is the usual definition, so I am more than likely missing some details since it is bilinear (like something about isomorphisms between vector spaces) but this is the bare bone version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy actually. To be precise $\Sigma$  is a **smooth spacelike Cauchy surface** of the spacetime and the considered space $V$ of solutions of the KG equations is made of solutions **smooth and with compactly supported Cauchy data on $\Sigma$**. Under these hypotheses, the relation between **Cauchy data** on $\Sigma$, $(f|_\Sigma, n_\Sigma \cdot\nabla f|_\Sigma)$ and corresponding solutions $f$  of the KG equation is one-to-one. In other words the Cauchy problem is **well posed**.

If $(f,h)=0$ for every $h$ then both $f$ and its derivative normal to $\Sigma$ are zero. This easily follows from the very form of the simplectic form and from the fact that we can choose the Cauchy data of $h$ arbitrarily and there is a corresponding $h$.

Hence, again in view of the well posedness of the Cauchy problem, $f$ must be  the zero solution of the KG equation.

Comment: $(f,h)=0, \forall h$ implies, for the well posedness, that the integral is $0$ for every possible pair $(h|_\Sigma, n_\Sigma \cdot\nabla h|_\Sigma)$, which implies that $(f|_\Sigma, n_\Sigma \cdot\nabla f|_\Sigma)=(0,0)$, which implies, for the well posedness, that $f=0$. Right?

Comment: Yes, right. You understood