# Symplectic basis for the real solution space of the covariant Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In lecture 12 of his course on "Quantum field theory for cosmology", that can be found for free on the web, professor Kempf makes the following statements.

Consider a real Klein-Gordon field $\phi$ in a globally hyperbolic spacetime, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

The covariant Klein-Gordon equation is

$$(g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+m^{2})\phi=0$$

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real-valued solutions to this equation.

Define the following bilinear form:

$$(f,h):=\int_{\Sigma} d\Sigma_{\mu}\sqrt g g^{\mu\nu} (f\partial_{\nu}h-h\partial_{\nu}f), \forall f,h \in V$$

where $\Sigma$ is any spacelike hypersurface.

This is a bilinear, antisymmetric, non-degenerate form, i.e. a symplectic form.

Ha says that Darboux theorem assures us that there exists a basis $\{v_{n}\}$ in $V$, such that

$$(v_{2n},v_{2n+1})=1$$
$$(v_{2n+1},v_{2n})=-1$$
$$(v_{n},v_{n'})=1, \text{otherwise}$$

This is called Darboux basis (and it is not unique).

The problem is that I have not found any references on the validity of this theorem on an infinite dimensional space. Is this really true even in the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/795947/2451

Comment: Without fixing a topology the issue is meaningless.

Comment: However, the Darboux theorem cannot generalise to the infinite dimensional case automatically.

Comment: Is assuming that such a basis exists a mistake in this setting? Maybe something else should be specified, but, in the end, it can be proven to be true.

My goal was to prove the existence of a basis of the form indicated in Birrell's chapter 3, which is not demonstrated there. In Kempf's aforementioned lesson, starting from Darboux's theorem, he arrives at showing the existence of a basis of that type. If the starting point is not legitimate, I have to look for another way.

Comment: The mistake is that there is no definition of basis!  I expect that it should satisfy something like this $f = \sum_i c f_i$ where the sum is infinite and $f$ is a solution of the KG equation. What is the meaning of that infinite sum? Is  it a pointwise convergence? What is the family of solutions $f$ where that formula is valid? Without these details all the issue is meaningless...Mentioning Darboux theorm  is incorrect and useless, also pedagogically, in my view.